# Cache server data globally and refresh views

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, userdefaults

I'm building an app that uses firebase for authentication and database functionality. Once a user signs up, a database record is stored for that user, containing some basic information like first name, last name etc.

Once a user logs in with his credentials I want to set a global variable (perhaps userDefaults?) which contains the user data for that specific user. Otherwise I have to fetch user data for every time I want to fill a label with for instance, a user's first name.

I managed to set userdefaults upon login and use this info in UIlables. But when I let users make changes to their data, of which some is important for the functioning of the app, I can update the server AND the userdefaults but the app itself doesn't update with the correct data. It keeps the old data in (for example) UIlables.

I would love to get some more insight on what the best work-flow is to manage situations like these.

When opening the app, i have a `tabBarController` set as `rootviewcontroller`. In the load of `tabbarcontroller` I have the following code retrieving the user data from firebase and saving it to `userdefaults`:

```swift
guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
            Database.database().reference().child("users").child(uid).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
                print(snapshot.value ?? "")


              guard let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] else { return }
                let firstname = dictionary["First name"] as? String
                let lastname = dictionary["Last name"] as? String

                print("first name is: " + firstname!)

                UserDefaults.standard.set(firstname, forKey: "userFirstName")

                print(UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "userFirstName"))


                self.setupViewControllers()


            }
```

Then I continue on loading in all the viewcontrollers in the tabBarController:

```swift
self.setupViewControllers()
```

During that process the labels in those viewcontrollers get filled in with the userdefaults data.

This is an example of a label being filled in with userDefaults but not being updated upon changing of userdefaults:

```swift
    let welcomeLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()  
        let attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Welcome ")
        attributedText.append(NSAttributedString(string: "\(UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "userFirstName")!)"))
        label.attributedText = attributedText
        label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 30, weight: .bold)
        return label
    }()
```

this is a function i'm using to update the first name (via a textfield filled in by the user):

```swift
    @objc func updateName() {
        guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
        Database.database().reference().child("users").child(uid).updateChildValues(["First name" : updateNameField.text ?? ""])

        UserDefaults.standard.set(updateNameField.text, forKey: "userFirstName")

        print(UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "userFirstName"))
    }
```

Comment: This looks like a case when you need to implement the Observable pattern using Notifications so that when new/updated data is saved other parts of your app gets notified about it and can update itself. See for instance [this article](https://www.swiftbysundell.com/posts/observers-in-swift-part-1)

Comment: @CvEijk What all information are you looking to store. Can you be more specific so I can help

Comment: An easier option would be to gather all code that updates the UI with user info in a view controller into one single method so when you save user data then just call that single method. Something similar to `tableView.reloadData()`

Comment: @JoakimDanielson He need something for refresh views. That's just setting up observers as you mentioned and refresh views on notifications. But does he need more. If that's the case, a better cache system is to be used. By the way, both will be easy to implement. We need to kow his requirement

Comment: I am looking to store a few images per user, their account data, and some history of app usage. So not that much actually, perhaps some notes

Comment: @AakashDave I think you are reading in a little to much into this question.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson can you explain?

Comment: @CvEijk so this is all the same user, or there are more?

Comment: @AakashDave The app should only have the information for the currently logged in user. Firebase ofcourse has more users stored. But in the app, only the current one.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I'm trying to create a global method that updates all of the fields containing user data, but am having trouble updating lets from different classes, how would I go about reaching/updating them in that function?

Comment: You can’t update different view controllers from one place, you need one `updateUI` method in each view controller. I also recommend you move the actual update of for instance a label text away from the `let`

Comment: Excuse me, is reloading what I should focus on? would I have to reload all of the views in the app? Or can I just reload certain elements?

Comment: @CvEijk, you can infact do it, where ever you update, you'll only have a single view present, right?. You just need to refresh the views. It's super possible. Reloading data is of no use. You need to create a way to refresh them. I'll post an answer soon

Comment: @CvEijk just confirm with me so I can let you know

Comment: @AakashDave i have 4 views in the tabbarcontroller but only one view in which i change user data yes

Comment: Alright, You'll have it :)

Comment: @CvEijk I have updated a detailed answer with the explanation. I personally implement this and works like charm. Let me know if there are any doubts. If satisfied accept and upvote it bro. Cheers!

Comment: Cheers mate! Happy to help

Comment: @AakashDave this has been buggin me for way too long haha, thanks for taking the time and effort to share your knowhow, super appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you'll have to organize things first. In a new file define constants such as below. These constant will be accessible in global scope unless `private`

**Constants.swift**

```
private let storedusername = "usname"
    private let storedName = "uname"
    private let displaypic = "udp"
    private let aboutme = "udesc"

    var myusername : String {
        get {
            return (UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: storedusername)!)
        } set {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(newValue, forKey: storedusername)
        }
    }

    var myname : String {
        get {
            return (UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: storedName)!)
        } set {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(newValue, forKey: storedName)
        }
    }

    var myProfileImage : Data {
        get {
            return (UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: displaypic)!)
        } set {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(newValue, forKey: displaypic)
        }
    }

    var myAboutMe : String? {
        get {
            return (UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: aboutme)!)
        } set {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(newValue, forKey: aboutme)
        }
    }
```

Now the next time you want to save anything in `UserDefaults`, you'll just do the following anywhere throughout your code base :

```
myusername = "@CVEIjk"
```

And to retrive it, just call it :

```
print(myusername)
```

**IMPORTANT NOTE --**

1. Always remember to initialize them. You can do this as the user signs up. As soon as they fill out their details and hit submit, just save them to these variables. That wouldn't cause unnecessary crash.
2. You'll have to save them at every location you perform updates regarding these nodes in the database.

Now, the refreshing views part. I am taking a scenario where your `ProfileView.swift` has the view and user goes to `EditProfile.swift` for updating the content.

You initialize all your observers the place where the update will have the immediate effect. Because the view immediately after the update matters. The rest will be called through the getter of the `aboutme`

**ProfileView.swift**

```
func openEditView() {

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(fetchUserDetails), name: Notification.Name("update"), object: nil)

        //setting this right before the segue will create an observer specifically and exclusively for updates. Hence you don't have to worry about the extra observers.

        perform(segue: With Identifier:)// Goes to the editProfile page
    }
```

This function will be initially called in viewDidLoad(). At this time you need to make sure you have all the data, else it will produce no values. But if you are storing everything as the user signs up, you are safe.

```
@objc func fetchUserDetails() {
        if uid != nil {
            if myname.count > 0 { // This will check if the variable has anything in the memory or not. Dont confuse this with [Array].count
                self.nameLabel = myname
            }
        }
    }
```

This function also acts an ab observer method. So when the notifications are posted they can run again.

Now, **EditProfile.swift**

In the block where you are updating the server, save the values and then create a `Notification.post` and put this method right before you `dismiss(toViewController:)`

```
   func updateUserCacheData(name: String, username: String, aboutme: String, ProfilePhoto: UIImage? = nil) {
        DispatchQueue.global().async {
            myname = name
            myusername = username
            myAboutMe = aboutme
            if self.newImage != nil {
                myProfileImage = self.newImage!.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1)!
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .refreshProfileViews, object: nil)
            }
        }
    }

    func updateToServerAndBackToProfileView() {
        self.updateUserCacheData(name: iname!, username: iusername, aboutme: iaboutme!)
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
```

As long as this goes back to `ProfileView`, your views will be instantly refreshed. You can keep an observer wherever you view will be first displayed after the dismiss. the rest will fetch updated content always. Also, don't forget to `deinit` your Observer in `ProfileView`

```
//This code is in ProfileView.swift
deinit {
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: Notification.Name("update"), object: nil)
    }
```

Also, in cases where the content might be empty, simply initialize it with empty content. For example, if user doesn't choose to add aboutme while signing up, you can just put

```
`myaboutme = ""`
```

This will create a safe environment for you and you are well set.